# how to insert data in elastic search index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i have created a index named - test. and as mapping as per following

```
{
 "test" : {
   "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "info" : {
             "type" : "nested"
          },
          "joining" : {
             "type" : "date"
          }
      }
   }
}
```

how to write a java code that adds data one by one to above index or suggest the example or tutorials

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the java code which can be easily used to index the data:, you can define a JAVA POJO which holds your index fields, **like in below code `UserRegistration` is a POJO holding the index props and than you can call below method from webservice or other methods which triggers indexing in your application.**

```
// ElasticSearch client
private RestHighLevelClient esclient = ...


// Jackson POJO-to-JSON mapper
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

public boolean register(UserRegistration userRegistration) throws IOException {

        final String userStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(userRegistration);
        final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(USERS_INDEX_NAME)
                .id(userRegistration.getUserId())
                .source(userStr, XContentType.JSON);
        IndexResponse indexResponse = esclient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return true;
    }
```

Please refer [JAVA HLRC index-api client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-index.html) for more details and code samples

Comment: before uploading i have to check that data is already present or not ....so how can I travers or check that is all documents under the test index??

Comment: @Jenny, you could simply use the `GetRequest`  if you know the id or you will have to search with the data, I would suggest ask a different question and I shall answer it, and before that please upvote and accept my answer :)

Comment: here is next question https://stackoverflow.com/q/63921602/13504695

Comment: @Jenny I see its already answered :( and thanks for marking answer, hope you upvoted as well :)