# how to insert unique data in Elasticsearch index document in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

this is my previous question -  [how to insert data in elastic search index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63918143/13504695)

index mapping is as follows

```
{
 "test" : {
   "mappings" : {
     "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "info" : {
          "type" : "nested"
        },
        "joining" : {
           "type" : "date"
        }
    }
}
```

how can i check the data of field is already present or not before uploading a data to the index

Note :- I dont have id field maintained in index. need to check name in each document if it is already present then dont insert document into index

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't have a `id` field in your mapping, you have to search on `name` field  and you can use below code to search on it.

```
public List<SearchResult> search(String searchTerm) throws IOException {
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX_NAME);
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        MatchQueryBuilder multiMatchQueryBuilder = new 
        MatchQueryBuilder(searchTerm, "firstName");
        searchSourceBuilder.query(matchQueryBuilder);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        SearchResponse searchResponse = esclient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return getSearchResults(searchResponse);

    }
```

Note, as you have `keyword` field instead of `match` you can use [termquerybuilder](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.9.1/org/elasticsearch/index/query/TermQueryBuilder.html)

And it uses the `utility` method to parse the `searchResponse` of ES, code of which is below:

```
private List<yourpojo> getSearchResults(SearchResponse searchResponse) {
        RestStatus status = searchResponse.status();
        TimeValue took = searchResponse.getTook();
        Boolean terminatedEarly = searchResponse.isTerminatedEarly();
        boolean timedOut = searchResponse.isTimedOut();

        // Start fetching the documents matching the search results.
        //https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search
        // .html#java-rest-high-search-response-search-hits
        SearchHits hits = searchResponse.getHits();
        SearchHit[] searchHits = hits.getHits();
        List<sr> sr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SearchHit hit : searchHits) {
            // do something with the SearchHit
            String index = hit.getIndex();
            String id = hit.getId();
            float score = hit.getScore();

            //String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
            Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = hit.getSourceAsMap();
            String firstName = (String) sourceAsMap.get("firstName");
            
            sr.add(userSearchResultBuilder.build());
        }
```

Comment: class SearchResult is from which package?

Comment: @Jenny its my own class, which parses the field from SearchResponse class of Elasticsearch, so in your case, you can use your POJO which defines your index in ES